Does DimensionsAI database store researchers' middle name?
I'm attempting to get the id (i.e. ur.015000016117.95) of different researchers in the DimensionsAI database and would like to use their middle name to disambiguate. The problem is that if I exact search someone like "Steven M Albelda" I won't get the profile "Steven Mark Albelda" which I'd like.
I've tried instead to use the "where" filter to filter by first name "Steven M" and last name "Albelda" but that still doesn't turn him up. Also using "for Steven M" gives me a bunch of names with the last name being Steven and the first name starting with M. I'd like something that recognizes Steven as first name, M as the beginning of the middle name, and Albelda as the last name.
Does Dimensions have any categories for middle name? The documentation for researchers only says it has first and last, how does it take into account the middle name? Does it just combine it with the first name?
Appreciate any insight into this.
